# MFC 64 bit code is slower than 32 bit on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c++, windows, performance, mfc, 64-bit

I run the following MFC code:

```
CArray<CString> l_Arr;
for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i)
{
  CString l_sStr;
  l_sStr.Format("%d", i);
  l_Arr.Add(l_sStr);
}
```

If I build 64 bit version the code runs about 2 times slower than 32 bit. I tried both Debug and Release versions. The times are the following:

> Debug 64 bit: 15085 ms
>  Debug 32 bit: 8128 ms
>  Release 64 bit:
>   8237 ms
>  Release 32 bit: 4695 ms

My configuration:

> Microsoft Visual Studio 2005
>  Version 8.0.50727.4039
>   (QFE.050727-4000)
>  Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64 bit
>   Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5645 @ 2.40GHz
>  Memory: 16.0 GB

I understand that this code can be optimized. I do not understand why there is such a difference.

@BarmakShemirani, I tried with vector as you suggested, you are right, the results are completely different. It looks like 64 bit code is even faster. Here are the results:

```
std::vector<CString> l_Arr; 
for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; ++i) 
{ 
  CString l_sStr; 
  l_sStr.Format("%d", i); 
  l_Arr.push_back(l_sStr); 
}
```

> Debug 64 bit: 3563 ms
>   Debug 32 bit: 4562 ms
>   Release 64 bit: 1140 ms
>   Release 32 bit: 1563 ms

Here is the optimized version with CArray:

```
CArray<CString> l_Arr;
static const int K_CNT = 2000000;
l_Arr.SetSize(K_CNT);
for (int i = 0; i < K_CNT; ++i)
{
  CString l_sStr;
  l_sStr.Format("%d", i);
  l_Arr[i] = l_sStr;
}
```

> Debug 64 bit: 2625 ms
>   Debug 32 bit: 2625 ms
>   Release 64 bit: 1015 ms
>   Release 32 bit: 1438 ms

Is CArray growing mechanism causes the code to run slower in 64 bit?

I looked into CArray growing code, essentially it allocates a new array and copies to it the old content every 1024 added elements. So I just simulated the allocation code with the following results:

```
static const int K_CNT = 2000000;
for (int i = 0; i < K_CNT / 1024; ++i)
{
  int l_nSize = (i + 1) * 1024 * sizeof(CString);
  BYTE* l_pData = new BYTE[l_nSize];
  memset(l_pData, 0, l_nSize);
  delete[] l_pData;
}
```

> Debug 64 bit: 10483 ms
>   Debug 32 bit: 4696 ms
>   Release 64 bit: 5803 ms
>   Release 32 bit: 2652 ms

Comment: Are the optimisation flags for 32 and 64 bit builds the same?

Comment: I tried it with VS 2013, I get the same numbers. It's 4 times faster for 64-bit with `vector<CString>`, but I don't know if that's an option for VS 2005.

Comment: This supposed phenomenon occurred w/16 bit apps running on Win95 - they were "faster".  A broader native data/address bus does not imply faster.  Wonder why VS remains a 32 bit app, including VS 2015?  Wider data/address bus means being able to handle 64 bit math and 64 bit addressing (that's a LOT of potential RAM to address directly) - if you tried to compare THAT, I am sure the 64 bit app would be faster than the 32 bit "equivalent" (e.g. try formatting or integer dividing two large 64 bit integers).

Comment: @cha, I didn't play with optimization, so the optimization flags are set to their original values: for the debug builds - disabled, for the release builds - Maximize Speed (/O2)

Comment: @franji1 compiling to x86_64 does not only increase the address and data width but also double (actually more than double) the number of registers which is very useful for most compute intensive programs. That's not counting many other improvements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 64-bit mode, pointers are twice as big. So it can happen that you have to allocate up to twice as much memory in the 64-bit version, just to store your pointers. This might be enough in itself to slow the program down.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot vote this answer up because of lack of enough reputation, but I think this is a good answer.